# Can't decode json. It's an array I encoded as json and stored as a cookie

Tags: php, json, cookies

Here is the output of what shows when I echo out the cookie directly, then try and json_decode it.

```
$_COOKIE['mycookie'] = {\"table_name\":\"wp_customtable\",\"time\":\"2013-09-26 08:18:23\",\"post_id\":null,\"referer\":\"www.bing.com\",\"keywords\":\"350 rear main seal replacement 11\",\"full_referrer\":\"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/search?q=350+rear+main+seal+replacement+11&go=&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=350+rear+main+seal+replacement+11&sc=0-32&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=dc09d67a2d214c8394bd39f2b28cf6cc\",\"ip\":\"123.45.67.89\"}

$cookie = $_COOKIE['mycookie'];
$output = json_decode($cookie, true);

var_dump($cookie);

string(392) "{\"table_name\":\"wp_customtable\",\"time\":\"2013-09-26 08:18:23\",\"post_id\":null,\"referer\":\"www.bing.com\",\"keywords\":\"350 rear main seal replacement 11\",\"full_referrer\":\"http:\\/\\/www.bing.com\\/search?q=350+rear+main+seal+replacement+11&go=&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=350+rear+main+seal+replacement+11&sc=0-32&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=dc09d67a2d214c8394bd39f2b28cf6cc\",\"ip\":\"123.45.67.89\"}

var_dump($output);
NULL
```

Comment: Why are `\"` 's escaped?

Comment: No clue. The data is an array originally, and this is the code I used to json encode it `json_encode($myarray)` EDIT  

To be more exact, this is the line  
`setcookie("mycookie", json_encode($myarray), time()+3600*24, '/', 'domain.com', false, false)`

Comment: Do you still have [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) enabled? It is deprecated, and should be disabled, but if you're currently working with it enabled it's time to check the whole project whether you can safely disable it...

Comment: Magic quotes are off.

Answer (score 2):

Just get rid of the slashes before the quotes:

```
json_decode(str_replace('\"', '"', $cookie), true);
```

[See fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AajToD)

Comment: Agreed, works, but not a fix for the original problem. The project is a WordPress plugin I'm creating, so I'd like to fix this the correct way so that it works on every server.